# Need a very specific screen capturing software for recording of gameplay while Skyping

Tags: screen-recording, streaming, skype

I need a 100% free (no ads, no trial, no limits, no watermarks, etc.) screen capture program that:

- Can record my microphone and the computer sound at the same time and without the sound from the speakers going into the microphone
- Can have a dynamically changeable screen capture area
- Doesn't capture 1024x768 as 1024x768, but as a lower resolution that I set because I either have to use low screen resolution (screws up desktop icons and probably crashes a graphics card driver) or maximize my pixelated Mario game (wastes space in the capture file)
- Has least possible lag&latency while playing Minecraft while Skyping and streaming the picture to Skype friends with least possible lag&latency
- Records with efficient codec compression like FFMPEG and into an AVI file

HyperCam 2 has non-linear de-syncing. OBS cannot set the capture area to newly created windows. I don't know what program does what I want it to do. I can see many people do things like this on YouTube so there has to be a way that I can do it. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Dynamically change the area? Any video I know cannot do that. Did you mean position?

Comment: I know that sometimes the camera zooms in for example onto an icon or text input or window. The user selects the area and the camera just pans in.

Comment: Perhaps [zoomit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/zoomit.aspx) can help.